# Validate sitemap.xml locally

Tags: xml, sitemap

I'd like to validate my sitemap xml LOCALLY not through a website (I know of http://www.webmasterwebtools.com/sitemap-validation/ and http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html but those won't work for me).

Answer (score -2):

You can use these XML schemas to validate:
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/

Comment: Can you kindly be more _specific_? How to do it for example in NodeJS? Thank you so much in advance